# Single positional indexer is out-of-bounds Error

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop

I have two dictionaries with 206 items each. Each team is a dataframe. Look at the Images to get an Idea of the dictionaries and items in it.

I want to replace Capacity values in all the sheets of 'voltage' dictionary as follows

```
x = (total number of rows in the sheet )/25

Capacity Value in Row1(index=0) - the sum of the values from Rows 1 to x in 
                                   "Current" column of 'copy'
Capacity Value in Row2(index=1) - the sum of the values from Rows x to 2*x in 
                                   "Current" column of 'copy'
Capacity Value in Row3(index=2) - the sum of the values from Rows 2*x to 3*x 
                                   in "Current" column of 'copy'
.
.
.
Capacity Value in Row25(index=24) - the sum of the values from Rows 24*x to 
                                     the last value.
```

To perform this, I have written code like this:

```
   for sheet in voltage:    
   for sheet in copy:
    n = ( round((len(copy[sheet]))/25) )
    
    for k in range(0,24):
        p = 1+((k+1)*(n))
        
        if k == 24:
            voltage[sheet]['Capacity'].iloc[k] = copy[sheet]['Current'].iloc[((k)*(n)):].sum()
        else:
            voltage[sheet]['Capacity'].iloc[k] = copy[sheet]['Current'].iloc[((k)*(n)+1):(p)].sum()
```

it shows the same error message.. Please help me with this.

Error Message : "Single Positional Indexer is Out of Bounds"

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This happened because some data was missing from an excel sheet under the Column name "Current". Once I added that data in the excel sheet, I was working fine.